# Ruby on Rails haml sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am passing a parameter to HAML pages and have successfully retrieved it.

```
%h1 Welcome to your History
%p
  %strong Name:
  = params[:name]

%table#houses
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th UserName
      %th User ID
      %th Email
      %th Rented House
      %th Start Date
      %th End Date
      %th Total Cost ($)
      %th Rating
```

I want to display a table according to the query `Select * from histories where name = params[:name]`.

How do I do this?

Comment: but where the problem is, have you tried to look to the documentation or you are just not looking for an easy way?!

Comment: I just need to do it quickly right now that is why seeking for help

Comment: Ankush, are you serious right now? you are wasting someone's time instead of quick look up into manual on some basic programming stuff? I'm voting to close your question, as something that can be found by trivial googling. There are tons of information. Be smart, don't waste someone's time, try to search basic things yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to do, and assumes that you've already executed the query in your controller, like so:

```
def history
  @histories = History.where(name: params[:name]);
end
```

In your view, you simply add rows and columns based on your data:

```
%h1 Welcome to your History
%p
  %strong Name:
  = params[:name]

%table#houses
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th UserName
      %th User ID
      %th Email
      %th Rented House
      %th Start Date
      %th End Date
      %th Total Cost ($)
      %th Rating
  - @histories.each do |history|
    %tr
      %td
       = history.name
      %td
       = history.user_name
      %td
       = history.user_id
      %td
       = history.email
      %td
       = history.rented_house
      %td
       = history.start_date
      %td
       = history.end_date
      %td
       = history.total_cost
      %td
       = history.rating
```

This will populate your table from the history data.